# c# MVC - Upon Form Completion, Attempts to Find View with Form Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

Overview: I am currently attempting to build a create account form. The form is rendered on another razor page. All works correctly, the form displays, sends the form data to a controller, sends data to a class, performs all DB actions, but then upon the completion of the previous items , the program attempts to find a page "CreateAccount.something" when all I want it to do for the time being is to return the initial view upon the return call.

Within said project, a form is displayed via: @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/AccountCreationForm.cshtml")

The form:

```
@model SuperDuperProject.Models.AccountCreationModel   // AccountCreationModel is only a class file containing the necessary variables
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAccount", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        ...
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </table>
}
```

The Controller file (HomeController.cs):

```
    ...
    public ActionResult UserLogin()   // the page containing the form
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateAccount(AccountCreationModel ACM)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CreateAccount within HomeController");

        Helpers.CreateAccount a = new Helpers.CreateAccount(...);
        a.AccountCreationQuery();

        return Index();   // ********** Doesn't seem to operate correctly **********
    }
```

Instead of returning Index() or anything placed there, the program attempts to find a CreateAccount view that does not exist.

What am I missing so I can simply return to a desired page, such as Index?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider returning a redirect result (following the PRG pattern) `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Comment: I do not see `Index()` in your code. What do you want to return?

Comment: Or `return View("Index")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateAccount(AccountCreationModel ACM)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CreateAccount within HomeController");

        Helpers.CreateAccount a = new Helpers.CreateAccount(...);
        a.AccountCreationQuery();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        // return Redirect("Home/Index"); alternatively can use Redirect
    }
```

You could consider using `RedirectToAction` or `Redirect`.

`RedirectToAction` returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action. `Redirect` takes a string type URL parameter and redirects to that specified the URL.

Check out this post for more info:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/595024/Controllers-and-Actions-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 public ActionResult UserLogin()   // the page containing the form
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateAccount(AccountCreationModel ACM)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CreateAccount within HomeController");

    Helpers.CreateAccount a = new Helpers.CreateAccount(...);
    a.AccountCreationQuery();

    return View("Index");  //index is the view here. You can define the view //name which you want to return from this controller action
}
```

By default controller searches for the view name as the name of the controller action that's why it is attempting to locate the view CreateAccount because controller action name is CreateAccount.